# Add column like Excels vlookup

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am working on adding a column multi_company to the table underneath. One that tells whether a user exists in two or more companies. I have come up with a working snippet, but keep thinking there must be a better and faster way.

```
customer     company      size      multi_company
justine      google       1         1
jack         google       5         0
grace        google       4         1
justine      microsoft    2         1
grace        microsoft    3         1
```

Performance is a real issue here, since the dataset will be large and this automated process should run often every day. Can anyone come up with a better way of solving this?

```
create table #1(customer varchar(255), company varchar(255), size int)
insert into #1(customer, company, size) values('justine', 'google', 1)
insert into #1(customer, company, size) values('jack', 'google', 5)
insert into #1(customer, company, size) values('grace', 'google', 4)
insert into #1(customer, company, size) values('justine', 'microsoft', 2)
insert into #1(customer, company, size) values('grace', 'microsoft', 3)
;
with cte as (
select customer
     , count(1) as multi_company 
  from #1 
 group by customer 
   having count(1) > 1
)
select #1.*
     , case when cte.multi_company is not null 
            then 1 
            else 0 end as multi_company 
  from #1 
  left join cte on #1.customer = cte.customer
```

Comment: That's how I would do it, keep it simple, leave optimization to SQL-Server (Except for the indexing of course).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are almost there. You just need to simplify it a bit:

```
select
  c.*,
  m.multi_company
from
  #1 c
  join
  (
    select
      customer,
      case
        when count(*) > 1 then 1
        else 0
      end as multi_company
    from #1
    group by customer
  ) m on c.customer = m.customer;
```

I get this output:

```
CUSTOMER        COMPANY         MULTI_COMPANY
--------------- --------------- -------------
justine         microsoft                   1
justine         google                      1
grace           microsoft                   1
grace           google                      1
jack            google                      0
```

Comment: This causes the 0 in multi_company to be displayed as null. Actually, that's not an issue in this case, so it's a nice enhancement, thanks!

Comment: I edited the query to get closer to the result that I think you are looking for.

Comment: This is indeed an enhancement, so I upvoted the answer. Saravatans option though fits better. Does the same, way less code and probably faster. I'll check the performance first, since that is my main concern.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help ???

```
SELECT
  customer,
  company,
  size,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(customer) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY customer) >1 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS multi_company
FROM cust
```